# How to install php script inside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed WordPress in the main domain [uberchecker.com](https://uberchecker.com) and installed a PHP script in [uberchecker.com/app](https://uberchecker.com/app), Now when I try to access any [app](https://uberchecker.com/app/online-ping-website-tool).
 I'm getting the error that page not found as it shows the Wordpress site...

How do i show the app page instead of the WordPress site showing me a 404 page?

My .htaccess file in the Wordpress root folder looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can use Wordpress template to write your php script and then use on wordpress as a page

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but if you want a separate script in a Wordpress directory, you can add a folder to the root of the directory called `app`, and place an index.php inside that folder like.

```
wp-admin/
wp-includes/
wp-content/
index.php
app/
-- index.php
```

The above will result in `www.wordpressinstallurl.nl/app` showing the contents of app/index.php

Secondly you also want to update your htaccess to prevent wordpress from routing all request to subfolders to the root index.php, you can do this by adding the following above the wordpress directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, That is precisely what i have done.. but the problem is when i try to access the page of a script, like this   `wordpressinstallurl.nl/app/exampleapp1`. i get a 404 error as it tries to show me the Wordpress page instead of the script page.

You an check my links. 

uberchecker.com -wordpress--works,  uberchecker.com/app- script installed--works, 
 uberchecker.com/app/meta-tag-generator --gets 404 error.

Comment: My bad, I added some extra info to my answer, you wan to make some changes to htaccess aswell!

Comment: i created the .htaccess as you said..in the Wordpress folder..but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you add your complete htaccess in your question so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I have added it to the question. The htaccess content is just the same as what you initially told.

Comment: Hmm that isn't possible, Wordpress needs a htaccess file of itself. Might be you have cant see hidden files on your server?

Comment: yes the .htaccess file is hidden by default, i checked that in my Wordpress directory using `ls -a` command. I can find the same in FileZilla. The content of htaccess is the same.. i dont know why its not working.

Comment: Are you sure inside `wordpressinstallurl.nl/app/exampleapp1` is an index.php?

Comment: No, wordpressinstallurl.nl/app/exampleapp1 is not an index.php file.The app folder has a index.php file and folders(admin, core, resources, theme, uploads) and each of these folders has separate index.php file inside them.

Comment: Just an unpdate, Im using nginx server. So that's why .htaccess file may not be working

Comment: did you end up solving the issue?